# Trunc in delphi

Tags: currency, truncate, delphi-xe

I am trying to separate currency number into two separate integer,

```
var
  StrNum: string;
  CurDecimalNum: currency;
  Amount : currency;
begin

    Amount := 1868.45;
    StrNum := FormatFloat('00', trunc(frac(Amount) * 100));   // this will return 44

    CurDecimalNum := frac(Amount) * 100;                      //Patch7
    StrNum := FormatFloat('00', trunc(CurDecimalNum));         //Patch7 but here I get 45

end.
```

I am doing it like this, but there is a problem in the first `FormatFloat()`, it returns 44 instead of 45.

I already have the solution in the code, I just had to separate the actions into two lines, I am just really curious why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you working with binary floating point representations when you want to perform decimal calculations? Although it is fair to say that Delphi's support for decimal data types is kinda terrible. You'd be better with a good third party decimal library. Or a programming language that had decent support.

Comment: You are using mathematical functions that operate on `Extended`/`Real` values, not on `Currency` values. So you are invoking implicit data conversions that are introducing issues due to floating-point inaccuracies, ie `frac(1868.45)` yields something like `0.44xxxxx...`, which then becomes `44.xxxxx...` when multiplied by 100, which is why `trunc()` is then returning 44 instead of 45.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to delete this line?

```
StrNum := FormatFloat('00', trunc(frac(Amount) * 100));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does deleting the line of code that the poster is asking about going to answer the question that is being asked? Your non-answer is the same as someone going to the doctor because their elbow hurts, and the doctor recommending that the arm should be amputated so that there is no more elbow.